# South African with Netherlands residence permit wanting to travel to UK

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, south-african-citizens

I am a South African wanting to travel to UK I have a residence permit valid till 2015 April for the Netherlands, this allows multiple access in Schengen countries, do I need a visa to visit the UK?

Comment: Are you aware that the UK is not part of Schengen?

Comment: Yes I am , that is the basis of the question so I may process visa issues should i need to

Comment: @ZaneBashir All the usual rules apply, your Dutch residence permit does not exempt you from any visa requirement. You can therefore look at previous questions on this site or use [the UKBA website](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-visas-and-immigration) to find out what you need.

Answer (score 1):

[South Africans need a visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_South_African_citizens) for the UK. Your Schengen visa doesn't automatically give you a UK visa but I'm sure it will make your application look much better. You can apply online at [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa).

Answer (score -2):

Yes you will need a visa. UK is not a part of Schengen. Go to the UK embassy to apply for a visa in Amsterdam.

Comment: There are no embassies in Amsterdam (UK or otherwise) and the consulate general does not handle visa applications. A few years ago, applicants had to go to Düsseldorf (I think you can now apply through a private company but I am not sure).

Comment: I double checked it. I notice they moved to The Hague. 

Contact info
Address Lange Voorhout 10
2514 ED 'S-Gravenhage
Telefoon (070) 427 04 27
Fax (070) 427 03 45

http://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/ambassades-consulaten-en-overige-vertegenwoordigingen/verenigd-koninkrijk/ambassade-van-het-verenigd-koninkrijk-van-groot-brittannie-en-noord-ierland-s-gravenhage


Here the official link of UK Embassy in The Hague. 
http://www.gov.uk/government/world/organisations/british-embassy-the-hague

Comment: I don't know that it “moved”, at least not recently. The government has been in the Hague for centuries and I assume embassies too. But many embassies in the Hague (including the British embassy) offer no consular services so the address is not very useful.